# Android Translate Animation causing Clicklistener problems

Tags: java, android, android-animation, translate-animation, clicklistener

Im having a problem with my Translate Animation that I created in android after the animation runs any clicklisteners that I had set remain in the exact coordinates that they were in before causing unusual issues, I have spent a few days researching this problem and have yet to find a fix, some suggestions that I have found included changing  my target development level to 4.0 and changing myLayout.layout(x,x,x,x), neither of these worked for me, any suggestions as to how I can change this code to to make any clicklisteners move with the layout?

```
upperView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.upperView);
    hiddenMenu = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.hiddenMenu);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    Integer width = metrics.widthPixels;

    upperView.getLayoutParams().width = width;
    hiddenMenu.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (width * 0.75);

    int theDistance = hiddenMenu.getLayoutParams().width;

    //Run animation
    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, theDistance - 0 , 0, 0);
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setFillAfter( true );
    upperView.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Try to find a way to "really" position the moved View object where the animation is supposed to end; i.e. implement a listener for the animation end and change its gravity or whatever, and make the translation effect non-persistent, in this way not relying on the translated position.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to know. android or the older sdk's keep the on click listener to the object's original location and it is important that you either create an invisible view at the new position for on click or use the newer [sdk](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html) .

Comment: To better explain this, the view is different from the object in older SDK. i.e. if you have an icon the physical view is only moved where as its original object still remains in that location. you could also move the original object with the help of an AnimationListener.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the TranslateAnimation not modify the view real position, only translate view's draw position.

Try using [PropertyAnimation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) to do this.
They already positioned to actually view, instead of just position the draw of view.

UPDATE:
Try use something like

```
upperView.animate().setDuration(1000).translationX(theDistance - 0);
```